# What does "in + times (e.g. 1 seconds)" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Get a coupon in 5 seconds.

The meaning of "in" when combined with time is confusing. "in 5 seconds" could mean "within 5 seconds" or "after 5 seconds", but how can I figure out which meaning is correct? Does "in 5 seconds" always mean "after 5 seconds"?

Comment: You can't figure out which meaning is correct from the language: this expression is ambiguous. In most contexts, it will be obvious which is meant, but sometimes there are genuine ambiguities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, it means, idiomatically, *within* that amount of time.

> Get a coupon in 5 seconds.

In other contexts, "in 5 seconds" could mean "*in 5 seconds' time*" - for example, "we will go home in half an hour" means that half an hour will elapse *before* you go home. In your example though, it means that the process of getting a coupon will take *5 seconds or less*; similarly "lose 5lb in one week!" is a promise that you will lose 5lb *over the course of a week*, not that it will start to happen in a week's time.